# Automator: use the passed file's filename in 'Run JavaScript' action

Tags: javascript, automator

I am having problems extracting the title of the passed file within the 'Run JavaScript' action.

When I pass the file into the 'Run JavaScript' action, it seems that of the two parameters of the prepared function, `run()`, - `input` and `parameters`, neither contain the file name.

If I add a 'Set Value of Variable' action before the 'Run JavaScript' action, it appears that the variable gets assigned the actual file.

How do I grab the filename of the passed file within the Run JavaScript' action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to produce an Automator Workflow that will provide the name of a selected file as the input for a **Run JavaScript** Action.  I do not have enough of a StackOverflow reputation to post a screenshot.  Here is the list of Actions:

**Ask For Finder Items** (I have it set to allow a single file)

**Run AppleScript Action:**

```
tell application "Finder" to set fileName to (item 1 of input)'s name

return fileName
```

**Run JavaScript**

The result of the **Run JavaScript** is the name of the file.
There may be a more efficient way to do this, but I am not familiar with it.

Good luck,

Answer (score 1):

Using Automator I could build a workflow to open a file using only JavaScript:

Run JavaScript

```
function run(input, parameters) {
   var FINDER = Application("Finder");
   FINDER.includeStandardAdditions = true;

   FINDER.activate();
   var origin_file = FINDER.chooseFile({withPrompt: "Please select a document to process:"});
   FINDER.open(origin_file);

   return input;
}
```

and a Folder Action workflow to display the path of a file moved to a folder using only JavaScript:

Run JavaScript

```
function run(input, parameters) {
   var app = Application.currentApplication();
   app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
   var text = "FileName = " + input[0];
   var options = { };
   app.displayAlert(text, options);

   return input;
}
```

I hope that could help